# Cast all object fields to boolean

Tags: javascript

I want to cast all object fields to boolean.

```js
function parseBooleanObject (obj) {
  const flagKeys = Object.keys(obj)
  return flagKeys.reduce(
    (newFlags, key) => (newFlags[key] = obj[key] === 'true'), {}
  )
}

const obj = { showVideo: 'true', isStudent: 'false' }
const parsedObj = parseBooleanObject(obj)
console.log('parsedObj: ', parsedObj)
```

But this code returns `false` instead of parsing fields to boolean

`{ showVideo: true, isStudent: false }`

Comment: You need to `return newFlags` from your reduce function

Comment: `newFlags[key] = obj[key] === 'true'` will return the value of the assignment, which is a boolean. The next time the `reduce` callback is invoked it's going to use *that* value as `newFlags`, so for iteration 2+, `newFlags` is always a boolean and you're assigning `true[key]` or `false[key`]

Comment: You can always spread the current object into a new one, and add the additional key: `.reduce((newFlags, key) => ({...newFlags, [key]: obj[key] === 'true'}))`

Comment: const castToBool = (obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(x => obj[x] = !!obj[x])); let a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 0, d: 'a', e: '', f: 'b' }; castToBool(a); console.log(a);

Comment: @UmairKhan that works for truthy/falsy values, but doesn't work for parsing OPs data where the values are `"true"` or `"false"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assignment operator** returns only the current key which gets assigned to **newFlags**, you need to return whole **newFlags** back.

Here i have used `,` operator to return newFlags after assignment.

```js
function parseBooleanObject (obj) {
  const flagKeys = Object.keys(obj)
  return flagKeys.reduce(
    (newFlags, key) => (newFlags[key] = obj[key] === 'true', newFlags), {}
  )
}

const obj = { showVideo: 'true', isStudent: 'false' }
const parsedObj = parseBooleanObject(obj)
console.log('parsedObj: ', parsedObj)
```

I will personally have them in two separate line in order to keep readability maintained

```js
function parseBooleanObject(obj) {
  const flagKeys = Object.keys(obj)
  return flagKeys.reduce(
    (newFlags, key) => {
    newFlags[key] = obj[key] === 'true'
     return newFlags
    }, {}
  )
}

const obj = {
  showVideo: 'true',
  isStudent: 'false'
}
const parsedObj = parseBooleanObject(obj)
console.log('parsedObj: ', parsedObj)
```

Comment: it's worth noting that this is using the comma operator - `(a, b)` evaluates to `b` and not _returning_ a tuple.

Comment: just curious, but if you'd actually use the second syntax, why did your first answer only show the comma operator version?  ;)

Comment: @Alnitak sure, but here eventually this is what will happen, since we are using implicit return so eventually it will return `b`

Comment: @Alnitak thats was just to keep code as close as possible to OP's code, i always bet on simple code :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't return the correct value from your `Array.reduce`.

Same answer as @Code Maniac, different syntax.

```js
function parseBooleanObject(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((tmp, x) => {
    tmp[x] = obj[x] === 'true';
    
    return tmp;
  }, {});
}

const obj = {
  showVideo: 'true',
  isStudent: 'false'
};

const parsedObj = parseBooleanObject(obj);

console.log('parsedObj: ', parsedObj)
```

Comment: I would like to call it better syntax instead of different syntax :)

Comment: @CodeManiac I wouldn't dare :p

Answer (score 0):

you have to return object from the reduce function

```
   function parseBooleanObject(obj) {
        const flagKeys = Object.keys(obj)
        return flagKeys.reduce(
            (newFlags, key) => {
                (newFlags[key] = obj[key] === 'true');
                return newFlags
            }, {}
        )
    }

    const obj = { showVideo: 'true', isStudent: 'false' }
    const parsedObj = parseBooleanObject(obj)
    console.log('parsedObj: ', parsedObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

different approach with `for...in` loop

```js
function parseBooleanObject (obj) {
  const parsed = {};
  for (let key in obj) parsed[key] = obj[key] === 'true';
  return parsed;
}

console.log(
  parseBooleanObject(
    { showVideo: 'true', isStudent: 'false' }
  )
);
```